# Displaying Image in Image Attachment

Tags: slack-api

According to the Slack API, if you provide a valid link to an image_url, that image will be displayed. I've tried this with the message builder [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fa%2FxVS7Qgv%22%2C%22thumb_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fa%2FxVS7Qgv%22%7D%5D%7D) but no image is ever displayed. I also tried this using cURL, and once again the image doesn't display. Any idea how to get the image to display? This is for use in creating a bot to send notifications through an incoming webhook. Thanks!

Image of JSON and corresponding message preview:

[image: Image of JSON and corresponding message preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seam to be two problems with your example.

1. You can not use both image and thumb together in the same attachment. If you want to use both in your message, just create another attachment.
2. When using imgur you need to use the direct image link, not the imgur page link.

Here is a working [example](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FUmu6cp6.jpg%22%7D%2C%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%2C%22thumb_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FUmu6cp6.jpg%22%7D%5D%7D).